# In ASP.Net form - why is content disappearing on hover of radio button?

Tags: asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I have this form, that works fine in most browsers, however in Internet Explorer 11, when I first load the page and hover over any radio button all content after the radio button control disappears. The content is still there (when I look at it using F12) but not displaying. It's a standard ASP.Net radio button control. Once I click on one of the radio buttons the problem goes away and the content reappears. The problem does not occur when I'm testing/debugging locally. It only happens once the application is published to the server.

Maureen

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to your IE Compatibility View settings.

Go to Tools --> Compatibility View Settings and change it there.

Comment: I've removed my site from Compatibility View settings and this has stopped the issue - however I have other ASP.net forms with radio button list controls that do not have this problem - with Compatibility View settings on. Any other reason why this might be happening on just this form? I need it to work with the site in Compatibility View.

Comment: First, I would use a tool to validate your CSS. Then I would start removing things like CSS links until the problem went away - in order to identify the root cause. Really a matter of narrowing it down.

Comment: Why is your form tag so complicated? Are you using JavaScript to submit the form? You should only need: <form runat="server">...

Answer (score 0):

I got it. My markup wasn't perfect. Just fixing a div that was out of place fixed it.